# OAuth2 bad interaction with method only @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

While implementing Spring Security's OAuth2, I was having a hard time getting any of the endpoints to respond to me.  When POSTing to /oauth/token, the org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping was telling me that POST was not allowed.  I eventually found the culprit in my mapping for OPTIONS requests:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
public void systemOptions() { }
```

The HandlerMapping for annotations eventually fails to find an exact match and loosens constraints to provide a helpful, "No direct match, but you could change media types or HTTP method" type exceptions.  This is great and all, but the exception that this HandlerMapping is throwing is preventing the DispatcherServlet from continuing to process the other HandlerMappings - one of which is the OAuth2 FrameworkMappings (which is what I'd like it to map me to in the first place).

My systemOptions() method exists as a RequestMapping only to support CORS OPTIONS requests from browsers - I have another filter that adds appropriate CORS related Headers to all requests.

My options now seem to be quite drastic and I'd like some community input before I jump into this deep end.  Should I handle the CORS OPTIONS requests totally inside of a filter?  Should I change the Order of my HandlerMappings?  Is there a better way for me to handle the CORS OPTIONS requests?

Answer (score 0):

I think most people use a `Filter` for CORS headers at this point (though Spring 4.2 should have some more granular support). If anything I'd say the problem is with the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` so I'd ask on Stackoverflow about that or raise an issue in JIRA, if I were you, and use a `Filter` in the meantime.

N.B. this is not really an OAuth question IMO. Maybe add "spring-mvc" to your tags?

Comment: Good points.  I'll use a `Filter` instead of the `RequestMapping` and tag this question as you suggested.